# REST API in new instances not working... existing instances fine

Tags: rest-api, connected-apps, user-profile

We've got some .NET apps that connect to salesforce REST API through a connected app. We created a new full sandbox from production but the REST API won't connect with the error {"error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"grant type not supported"}.

I've checked and double checked the connected app, the service account and the permissions and they're all correct.

Does anyone have any ideas on what's wrong?

Comment: Can you show the URL you're trying to hit with the secret and id redacted

Comment: I had added the interface URL wrong! Thank you!